# interface variable declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, interface

`IMytask` is the `interface` which has some method, `Mytask` inherits `IMytask`

why below one is always recommended way to declare a variable?

```
IMytask xyz = new Mytask();
```

Can you please help me to understand, What is the use and importance of doing this ?

Comment: _"What is the use and importance of doing this?"_ - I note that doing that harms performance as all method calls (via an `interface` type) will have to be virtual-calls (involving pointer indirection via a vtable lookup) whereas if you maintain a "static" type then the compiler can ensure those calls are non-virtual (i.e. faster). Additionally, you _really shouldn't_ do this when your implementation is a `struct` or other value-type as that means you have to _box_ the value-type on the heap, ew.

Comment: @Dai on the virtual-call aspect; increasingly, the JIT is getting much better at devirtualizing even through interfaces; on both aspects, there's also "constrained calls" (via generics), which allows interfaces to be used with value-types with neither virtual calls nor boxing

Comment: @MarcGravell Yep - (I didn't mean for my comment to sound so absolute or universal; you are entirely correct).

Comment: What makes you think that is the recommended way to declare a variable?

Comment: Interfaces are reference types in C#. The interface type receives the implementation class object. It is an object-oriented feature.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't necessarily "important" - it is entirely possible for interfaces to be unnecessary and superfluous - and it is possible for them to be essential. That is contextual. I certainly wouldn't say that it is a default / automatically recommended approach; I would have just used:

```cs
var xyz = new Mytask();
```

or

```
Mytask xyz = new();
```

Either of which would leave `xyz` types as `Mytask`, not `IMytask`.

Interfaces separate *API* from *implementation*. This allows types to implement a particular API without having to share any kind of type model, or allows for the consumer to use an API without knowing *which actual concrete types* will be used - just: what API they provide.

For example, "sort" functions in the .NET framework code (`List<T>` etc) might use the `IComparable<T>` or `IComparer<T>` APIs, but the types that *provide* the compare functionality are often in your code. The framework can't know about your code, just the interface.

Likewise, interfaces *may* make it easier to inject, mock, or test code.

Or: it might add nothing useful! If there is exactly one type that implements an interface, and the consuming code could just have easily have used the type directly: the interface is probably overkill.

There are also some side aspects in terms of "explicit interface implementation" (which allows a type to implement methods of an API without having them on the public/default API of the type). Again, whether this matters: contextual.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say this is **always** the recommended way to declare a variable involving a type implementing an interface but it often makes sense to do s. An interface represents a contract and by declaring a variable of that contract, you decouple the value of the variable of the implementation.

Consider this interface:

```
interface IHelloWorld
{
   void Hello();
}

// You could have two implementations of the interface

class Foo : IHelloWorld
{
   public void Hello()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello Earth!");
   }
}

class Bar : IHelloWorld
{
   public void Hello()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello Mars!");
   }
}
```

A variable of type IHelloWorld could now represent either type Foo or type Bar's implementation.

```
IHelloWorld impl = new Foo();

impl = new Bar();

impl.Hello();
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you would NOT declare a local variable as an interface; instead, you would just declare it as the concrete type or use `var` (which has the same effect as specifying the concrete interface in this case). This can avoid certain performance hits, as mentioned in the other answers.

However, it's important to know that in some cases you will see a *functional difference* between declaring a variable using an interface and using `var` or the concrete type. This can happen if the concrete type uses [`explicit interface implementation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) to implement an interface.

An example will illustrate. Consider the following simple interface:

```
public interface IDemo
{
    void SayHello();
}
```

Now consider this implementation:

```
public sealed class Demo: IDemo
{
    public void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wave Goodbye");
    }

    void IDemo.SayHello() // Explicit implementation of "SayHello()".
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    }
}
```

With that, look at the following usage:

```
Demo demo = new Demo();
demo.SayHello(); // Outputs "Wave Goodbye"

IDemo idemo = demo;
idemo.SayHello(); // Outputs "Hello!"
```

So if you call `SayHello()` via the concrete class, you get a DIFFERENT result from calling `SayHello()` via the interface.

In cases like this, it depends on the context whether you need to use the concrete class or the interface (and I'd say that ending up with this dilemma is the result of a bad design).